# How the Rig Veda text was formatted originally when first codified into Sanskrit

Tags: rig-veda, sanskrit

The [Rig Veda](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv01084.htm) has formatting like this (with the `|` pipe characters):

> को अद्य युङकते धुरि गा रतस्य शिमीवतो भामिनो दुर्ह्र्णायून |
>   असन्निषून हर्त्स्वसो मयोभून य एषां भर्त्यां रणधत स जीवात ||
>   क ईषते तुज्यते को बिभाय को मंसते सन्तमिन्द्रं को अन्ति |
>   कस्तोकाय क इभायोत राये.अधि बरवत तन्वे को जनाय || [Rigveda 10.84.17]
>
> ko adya yuṅkte dhuri ghā ṛtasya śimīvato bhāmino durhṛṇāyūn |
>   asanniṣūn hṛtsvaso mayobhūn ya eṣāṃ bhṛtyāṃ ṛṇadhat sa jīvāt ||
>   ka īṣate tujyate ko bibhāya ko maṃsate santamindraṃ ko anti |
>   kastokāya ka ibhāyota rāye.adhi bravat tanve ko janāya ||

I am wondering how the Rigveda looked when it was first written down. I understand they were passed down orally for thousands of years, but when it was first written down in Sanskrit, was it written with these punctuation markers or not? What did the "original" Sanskrit texts look like?

Comment: You should do a time travel to know this :-) @Lance Pollard

Comment: Sanskrit has 'stops' not punctuation markers in your sense of the word. The Rg veda was written in 'old' sanskrit not 'modern' sanskrit. Parchment and paper do not survive fro thousands of years, the only thing that survives is stone. There is no way to know what the 'original' writing was. It was because parchment and paper did not survive that the texts were handed down verbally for thousands of years.